# how to read ConnectionStrings

Tags: vb.net

This is not working.. any ideas?

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YourConnectionString").ConnectionString
```

Error

"ConfigurationManager not declared"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And...

Have you added a reference to the System.Configuration assembly?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have

```
Imports System.Configuration
```

in your code? And a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may need to add a reference to `System.Configuration` .